# Automation in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, automation

I am using Eclipse and have a few simple tasks(such as uploading files to a server) I would like to automate. Where should I be looking, is something like ANT applicable here?
Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the external tools of eclipse (see [eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-exttools.htm)).
As stated in ["FAQ How do I add my own external tools?"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_my_own_external_tools%3F):

> External tools are applications or scripts that typically act as extensions to your development environment. For example, they may be used to execute scripts to package and deploy your application or to run an external compiler on your source files.
>   **External tools allow an end user to achieve a basic level of integration for a non-Eclipse-aware tool without writing a plug-in**.
>   External tools are created and configured via `Run > External Tools > External Tools` or from the drop-down menu on the Run button with the toolbox overlay.

That way, your script (.bat, ant, maven, whatever you want) can be run with a simple click on the external tools menu.

You can indeed associate an [external tool to ant](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_Ant%3F), since:

> The Ant UI as provided in Eclipse comes with a first-class Ant build-file editor, including syntax highlighting, Content Assist, templates, and content formatting.
>   This editor is automatically associated with files named build.xml and can be associated with other file names from the `Workbench > File` Associations preference page.
>
> The Ant UI also has a wizard for running Ant scripts and a toolbar button for repeating previous builds.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/images/et_dialog.png))</sub>

Comment: I didn't even think of that, but I use External Tools backed with scripts quite a bit too - nice suggestion. +1

Answer (score 2):

Maven is another solution. There are many mojos (custom plugins) for existing tasks that are highly configurable, or if you get stuck you can write your own.

The trade off is the setup and learning curve can be fairly steep, so I guess it boils down to what you need it for, if you'll reuse it, etc, etc.

Comment: Maven is a build / dependency management tool for BIG projects. It most definitely is not something suitable for "a few simple tasks".

Comment: I think that is a matter of opinion\subjective. But, as such, you are entitled to it.

Comment: I've used Maven - I even somewhat liked it. But there's nothing subjective about "Ant is a lot easier to deal with than Maven if all you need is to perform a few simple tasks" statement, especially considering that Eclipse has a very nice built-in integration with Ant. You can google "maven ftp upload" vs "ant ftp upload" for a simple illustration.

Comment: I'm not comparing Ant to Maven - heck I don't really even know Ant all that well. If you think it is the best solution, then post it. But I stand by my opinion that a project does not have to be huge to use maven.

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse Monkey](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Monkey_Overview) is an atempt to make Eclipse scriptable to automate tedious tasks.

Comment: This project appears to be dead, but I think it might be exactly what I want. Is there some sort of successor to it?

Comment: The [Eclipse EASE](https://www.eclipse.org/ease/) project is a valid successor of the Eclipse Monkey. Have a look there...